# Prevent Javascript execution in jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div that contains some html and a lot of Javascript

```
<div id="mydiv">
<p>Hello Philippines</p> my first time in Philippines is nice
<script type="text/javascript">alert("how was it became nice?");</script>
well I experienced a lot of things
<script type="text/javascript">alert("and how about your Japan's trip?");</script>
well its more nicer ^^ but both countries are good! hahah
</div>
```

I want to put the non-Javascript code and Javascript code in two separate variables:

```
var html = $("#mydiv").html();
```

My problem here is that my javascript is executing, which makes me stop to create the code I want which is the storing of javascript and non-javascript to two different variables.

1. how can I stop the javascript codes from executing when they are
   get inside the div?
2. how can I store the javascript and non-javascript code into two different variables safely?

**NOTE: I need the stored javascript for later execution**

Comment: Put your javascript code inside the funciton. They won't be executed until they have been called.

Comment: 1) use `text` instead of `html`, 2) you probably need some regex to separate them

Comment: when are you going to run the javascript? your script will run on page load that what i see.

Comment: well i was able to think about it but the problem here is the javascript is end-user defined code and I can't let them type the function every time

Comment: well there is an user-event(a button click) that the javascript code will be executed as the end-user's desire

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way,  that doesn't mean you have to place script elements in the html at all. You can bind click handlers to elements from separate script to alert the messages...

Comment: well this is what my professor wants.. he wants me to put everything in a contenteditable div with the scripts then seperate the questions using an alert()

Comment: can someone tell me why I got a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `code` tag instead of `script`:

html:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<p>Hello Philippines</p> my first time in Philippines is nice</p>
<code>alert("how was it became nice?");</code>
well i experienced a lot of things
<code>alert("and how about your Japan's trip?");</code>
<p>well its more nicer ^^ but both countries are good! hahah
</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
var html = $('#mydiv *').not('code').html()
var code = $('#mydiv code').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dMDy5/3/

Comment: hehe you just gave me the answer! well thank you ^^ but is there any workaround to handle with script tags instead of code tags?