# How to prevent javascript execution when using jQuery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to insert customer created content from an input textarea using `$.html()` of jquery to another `div` on the page for a live preview feature

But if customer typed javascript inside the content, like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('abc');
</script>
```

When calling this with `.html()`, the javascript will get executed, and if I use `.text()`, then the content will not be regarded as html.

How could I fix this? I created a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/larryzhao/VL82f/

Update:
Maybe I need to made it more clear, I am doing a preview for markdown. So user enters markdown on the textarea, and I converted to html, and display it to the `div#dest`. What if the user enters script as displayed above? Is there any way to keep the original type but not execute it? If there's not, then I think I would just write a regexp to wipe the script block out I think..

I found two online markdown tool:
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus  this one executes it
http://www.ctrlshift.net/project/markdowneditor/ and this one just wipe the script block out

Comment: didnt this help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373703/prevent-javascript-execution-in-jquery-html

Comment: You want the JavaScript is executed or not? You would have to create a regex to not insert the <script> in the preview.

Comment: Why are you having a customer type html?

Comment: You are contradicting your requirements? On one hand you want the preview and render markup/code (html and javascript) but you don't want a certain type (javascript)

Comment: Maybe consider using regex to add src="" to the script tags, which will make them do nothing. After you insert, you can remove the tags if you like.

Comment: @ShankarCabus no I don't want them to be executed. Yes, I want to see the alternatives, if there's not any, I will go the regex way.

Comment: @hayk.mart looks interesting, I may try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not locate a `<script>...</script>` and escape the characters in the section of the code?

For example:

```
<script src="test/javascript>
var userInput=document.getElementByID("#input");
..
..
..
</script>


&lt;script src=&quot;test/javascript&gt;
var userInput=document.getElementByID(&quot;#input&quot;);
..
..
..
&lt;/script&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a HTML sanitizer for JavaScript? If so, this is the way to do it. As a note, this is very *not easy* to do correctly, so a naive regex is usually insufficient. If you're saving this somewhere through an application, the preview feature could leverage that sanitizer by posting and getting back the cleaned up version.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace script tags with someting else so that you only see alerted value in preview, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#source').on('keydown', function(){
       var content = ($(this).val()).replace(/(<\s*\/?\s*)script(\s*([^>]*)?\s*>)/gi ,'$1jscript$2')
        console.log( content );
        $("#dest").html( content );
    });
});
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VL82f/12/)

Comment: This has side effects. If type `i love javascript.`, then will be `i love javajscript.`

Comment: @xdazz thanks for the info, replaced the replace thing, it should work even when string contains script

Answer (score 1):

If the text the user enters stays on the client then **why does it matter if a user wants to XSS himself??** And if the text goes back to the server then you sanitize it there, so that if other users see the input, they'll see a cleaned-up input.

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize user input, remove xss.

See [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/tree/49099c19e4ac303c4e11574007907960911b26c2)

Comment: I am not sure how to use it, but I found it when I searched for JavaScript repositories in github having `function xss_clean(`.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to create a regex to not insert the `<script>` in the preview:

`<script (.|\n)*?>(.|\n)*?</script>`

or try it:

```
function stripScripts(s) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;
  var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
  var i = scripts.length;
  while (i--) {
    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
  }
  return div.innerHTML;
}

alert(
  stripScripts('<span><script type="text/javascript">alert(\'foo\');<\/script><\/span>')
);
```